# MySQL-Auto increment

Tags: mysql

I have a table `t1` like this

```
no    name    number
1      A        25
1      C        25
2      DF       36
3      JS       79
3      H        79
3      KO       79
```

Initially the table is blank. I will import data into columns `name` and `number`. I want to set column `no` to start at 1 and automatically increase by 1 everytime the value in `number` change.

Really appreciate if someone could help me with this

Comment: I think your `question title` already answered this problem. You can set column `no` to Auto Increment and mysql will do it for you.

Comment: but it will increase by 1 for every row, not when the value of `number` changes

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstood, so you mean it will increase when number column has modified/updated and it's not unique column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use trigger on your table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER gen BEFORE UPDATE ON t1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF NEW.number <> OLD.number THEN
             SET NEW.no = OLD.no + 1;
     END IF;
END;
```